# Redirect requests calling to a non-root directory for js and css files to the same server on different port with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect requests calling to a non-root directory as well as all its sub-directories for js and css files, to the same server on different port with `.htaccess`.

Example:

```
www.domain.com/example_directory_with_htaccess/foo/bar.js
```

will be redirected to:

```
www.domain.com:1994/foo/bar.js
```

and

```
www.domain.com/example_directory_with_htaccess/foo.css
```

to

```
www.domain.com:1994/foo.css
```

What I have so far is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ http://127.0.0.1:1994/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

But using this `.htaccess`, I can only redirect to `www.domain.com:1994/suffix`
where `suffix` is one the suffices indicated in the configuration.

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example_directory_with_htaccess/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js))$ http://127.0.0.1:1994/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked out! Although to connect to a different port, one would need to add it in the .htaccess file.

Comment: @andrew you're right, I removed it to test in local ;)